# Edit user defined object in JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm writing data to postgres from kafka topic using Java,

I'm looping the records from kafka using below code

```
 for (SinkRecord record : records) 
 {  
   log.info("new set records: {}", record); 
   log.info("The value before modified: {}",record.value());
 }
```

Getting the following output when I'm printing record

```
SinkRecord{kafkaOffset=1, timestampType=CreateTime} ConnectRecord{topic='DES.EMPLOYEE_INCOME', kafkaPartition=0, key=Struct{EMPID=2
}, keySchema=Schema{com.attunity.queue.msg.New.DES.EMPLOYEE_INCOME.KeyRecord:STRUCT}, value=Struct{data.EMPID=2,data.NAME=feb,data.SALARY=10000,operation=REFRESH,timestamp=}, valueSchema=Schem
a{DataRecord:STRUCT}, timestamp=1678699184106, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}
```

Getting the follow output when I'm printing record.value()

```
Struct{data.EMPID=2,data.NAME=feb,data.SALARY=10000,operation=REFRESH,timestamp=} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbW
riter:80)
```

From the `record.value` object I would like filter out operation and timestamp,

After editing the `record.value`, Expected output would looks like below,

```
Struct{data.EMPID=2,data.NAME=feb,data.SALARY=10000} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbW
    riter:80)
```

how to do it,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,

```
final Struct value = record.value();
String operation = (String) value.get("operation");
Long timestamp = (Long) value.get("timestamp");
```

https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc//org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html

Otherwise, you would not do this in Java. You can use [ReplaceField$Value](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html) to `blacklist` the operation and timestamp fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm looking to update that object not to extract. Please find my updated Query.

Comment: Structs have a put function, if you want to update fields/values, as you can see in the Javadoc. Or, as mentioned, you can use a Transform to remove or **`blacklist`** the `operation,timestamp` fields. You dont need to do this in Java

Comment: @Onecricketeet, thanks for the info. I'm writing the data into two table, one is the destination table where I need to filter out operation and Timestamo column and to another table I need to write all the columns.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend deploying two separate connectors. One with the linked transform, and one without. Or you can simply create a VIEW in the database with only the fields you want to show from the original table